# How to hide item from left menu from admin

Tags: admin, magento-2.2.5, adminmenu

Just want to hide 'MagePlaza' from left navigation, which make client confuse.

I am trying to find simple and easy solution.

[image]

Comment: Please follow this link to do this https://tagvibe.com/magento2/hide-admin-menu-based-on-system-config-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to change in code then create new role for your client and add all resource except mageplaza and assign that rule to your client admin.

This link will help you to create role.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-user-role-magento-2.html

Comment: yes I did this for time period, but looking for solid solution.

Comment: I think this way is good because if you change in mageplaza xml file and in future if you update extension then you have to change in same file again so better to create role

Comment: valid point (thumbs up)

Answer (score 3):

Goto your module directory in `etc` > `adminhtml` > `menu.xml`

add `<remove id="menu_id"/>` before ending `<menu>` node.
`menu_id` is a identifier which you set in `<add>` node `id` attribute.

Comment: getting security error

Comment: add `<remove id="Mageplaza_Core::menu" />` in `<menu>` node before ending. i have updated the answer let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed this module via composer then you have to follow below directory:
[Your_Projetc_Folder_Name]/vendor/mageplaza/module-core/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml
and comment the code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd"> 
<!--<menu>
            <add id="Mageplaza_Core::menu" title="Mageplaza" module="Mageplaza_Core" sortOrder="50" resource="Mageplaza_Core::menu"/>
            <add id="Mageplaza_Core::documentation" title="Documentations" module="Mageplaza_Core" sortOrder="999" resource="Mageplaza_Core::documentation" parent="Mageplaza_Core::menu"/>
            <add id="Mageplaza_Core::marketplace" title="Mageplaza Marketplace" module="Mageplaza_Core" sortOrder="10" action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/mpmarketplace" resource="Mageplaza_Core::marketplace" parent="Mageplaza_Core::documentation"/>
            <add id="Mageplaza_Core::userguide" title="User Guides" module="Mageplaza_Core" sortOrder="20" action="mpcore/index/userguide" resource="Mageplaza_Core::userguide" parent="Mageplaza_Core::documentation"/>
        </menu>--> 
</config>
```

Otherwise you can follow @Ravi's way.

Comment: You should never make changes in your vendor folder

Answer (score 0):

Comment below code

> /app/code/Mageplaza/Core/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<!-- <menu>
<add id="Mageplaza_Core::menu" title="Mageplaza" module="Mageplaza_Core" sortOrder="50" resource="Mageplaza_Core::menu"/>
<add id="Mageplaza_Core::documentation" title="Documentations" module="Mageplaza_Core" sortOrder="999" resource="Mageplaza_Core::documentation" parent="Mageplaza_Core::menu"/>
<add id="Mageplaza_Core::marketplace" title="Mageplaza Marketplace" module="Mageplaza_Core" sortOrder="10" action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/mpmarketplace" resource="Mageplaza_Core::marketplace" parent="Mageplaza_Core::documentation"/>
<add id="Mageplaza_Core::userguide" title="User Guides" module="Mageplaza_Core" sortOrder="20" action="mpcore/index/userguide" resource="Mageplaza_Core::userguide" parent="Mageplaza_Core::documentation"/>
</menu> -->
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the menu item with a custom module. It's important that the module load after the module you want to override, in this case `Mageplaza_Core`, so you specify it in the `module.xml` under `sequence`. Then you can remove the item by ID in `etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`.

**`app/code/YourOrg/YourModule/etc/module.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="YourOrg_YourModule" setup_version="1.0.0" active="true">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Mageplaza_Core"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**`app/code/YourOrg/YourModule/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <remove id="Mageplaza_Core::menu" />
    </menu>
</config>
```